# Add new key value to json node in java

Tags: java, json

I have JSON file :

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"abc",
   "addressDetails":
      {
        "City":"NewYork"
      }
}
```

I wanted to add one more key-value ("pinCode" : "414141") to the node 'addressDetails'.

I tried using :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(new File("D://test.json"));
ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
node.with("addressDetails").put("pinCode", "414141");
```

But it's not getting added, Is there any way I can do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

you should modify the file path

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode nodes = mapper.readValue(new File("D:\\test.txt"), 
ObjectNode.class);
nodes.with("addressDetails").put("pinCode", "414141");
mapper.writer().writeValue(new File("D:\\test.txt"), nodes);
```

Comment: of course! u can write any file extension  eg. "D:\\test.log"

Comment: @sForSujit yes Its giving FilenotfoundException after changing extension

Comment: @Vinod you need to use a file that exists

Comment: @Vinod u lost {mapper.writer().writeValue(new File("D:\\test.txt"), nodes);}

Comment: @linnan Hey cool, My mistake ,I was not overriding it. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you add your value to a new JsonObject (`node`), and not the one (`root`) that you've read in. So basically, you'll have to add it to `root`. But to be able to do that, you'll have to cast it to an `ObjectNode`, as `JsonNode` does not provide any methods to add to the node.

So, try something like the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(new File("D://test.json"));
ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) root;
node.with("addressDetails").put("pinCode", "414141");
mapper.writer().writeValue(new File("D:\\test.txt"), node);
```